# Socket.io with nestjs does not work on kubernetes with traeffik

Tags: kubernetes, socket.io, nestjs, traefik, traefik-ingress

unfortunately I get a Cors problem with socket.io under nestjs. A GET request goes through successfully!

I deploy the whole nest application on Kubernetes. I suspect it is due to the ingress and traffic config.

Do any of you have the experience of how to write my ingress yaml so that I can fix the cors issue?

It works locally!

That would be my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: k3s-ms-example-de
  namespace: k3s-ms-example-de
  labels:
    author: xxx
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: http,https,wss
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: traefik-websocket
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares.traefik-websocket.headers.forceSTSHeader: ''
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto: https

spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.example.de
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: k3s-ms-example-de
              servicePort: k3s-ms-port

  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.example.de
      secretName: k3s-ms-example-de-tls # Secret containing TLS certificate and key
```

How can use socket.io with ingress and traeffic?